# Can pytest work with test that use argparse and have pytest ignore arguments intended for my test and have my test ignore arguments for pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I has some python scripts that use argparse for input and is working fine. I want to use pytest to test these scripts.

I cannot figure out how to tell pytest to ignore input arguments intended for my test. Also how to tell my test to ignore input arguments intended for pytest.

For example, I want to use pytest -s option.
I had to define the -s option in my test script even though my test has nothing to do with this argument.
Also in my script all arguments must have defaults.

I cannot figure out a way to pass in input arguments from the command line intended for my test and have pytest ignore these arguments.

I wrote the following script but I cannot pass in the port number as pytest will flag an error:

```
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --port
```

Also I had to define `-s` option in my test that is intended for pytest.

Here is the test script:

```
import argparse

import pytest
from litellm import completion


def test_main(options):

    model = f"ollama/{options['model']}"
    port = options["port"]
    response = completion(
        model=model,
        messages = [{ "content": "Hello, how are you?","role": "user"}], 
        api_base=f"http://localhost:{port}"
    )
    print(f"model {model} response {response}")

@pytest.fixture
def options():
    return Options()

def Options():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, help='repeatcnt', default=11434)
    parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, help='model', default="llama2")
    parser.add_argument('-s', action='store_true')
    return vars(parser.parse_args())
```

Here is the error when I tried to pass in the port number:

```
(venv) kenneth@kpc:~/learning/litellms$ pytest -s --port 8000
/home/kenneth/learning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:331: PluggyTeardownRaisedWarning: A plugin raised an exception during an old-style hookwrapper teardown.
Plugin: helpconfig, Hook: pytest_cmdline_parse
UsageError: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --port
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /home/kenneth/learning/litellms
For more information see https://pluggy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#pluggy.PluggyTeardownRaisedWarning
  config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --port
```

What I am hoping is have a way to tell pytest the following arguments are for the test script and have pytest ignore them. Also have my test to ignore input arguments that are intended for pytest.
Right now I do not have a way to provide input arguments from the command line and I have to use defaults to make it work such as the default for port.

Comment: Usually two dashes indicate the end of arguments. Did you try that? `pytest --arg-for-pytest -- --arg-for-your-code`

Comment: I tried this but still failed:  pytest -s -- --port 8000   The error is: ERROR: file or directory not found: --port

Comment: `pytest -s yourTestCase.py -- --port 8000`? ...but I don't know if the test case should accept arguments in the first place. Usually a test should be self-contained, and you just run it. Hard-code all your arguments in e.g., a parameterized test. If you want to test your argument parser, also hardcode the arguments you pass in your test code.

Comment: This seems like a design problem: if you are testing options processing, you should not be passing options to pass on the command line. You should be providing test values to `argparse.parse_args()` directly.

Comment: The script came first and it uses argparse to pass in input arguments even though most arguments have defaults.
The script takes a dictionary from the return values from argparse via return vars(parser.parse_args())
Then I added pytest and was trying to get them to work together but did not have much luck.
I found that with pytest I need to use pytest_addoption. I added the following in conftest.py:
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--port', type=int, help='port')

Comment: In my test I added the following line to retrieve the port value:
def test_main(options, pytestconfig):
    port = pytestconfig.getoption("port")
Now passing the port value works now.
pytest -s --port 11434

Comment: I decide not to use argparse to pass in arguments to my test because it is too difficult to get it right to cover different cases. Does anyone knows there is any way to do this reliably? For my case I have existing functionality already written that works with argparse to pass in input. It would be nice that I can use pytest and still able to utilize the same input. @Robert mentioned that -- option might work but I could not get it to work. Perhaps I am not doing it right. If there is a way to do this would be great.

Comment: This is getting confusing now. What are you trying to test? How your script parses its arguments? Can you [edit] your question and adjust the question text to incorporate what's in the comments here, and also add a [mcve] (including the code you want to test)?